# Adding hatches to imshow - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Basically, what I'm trying to do is the idea explained in the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045709/selective-patterns-with-matplotlib-imshow) question.

I plot an image 100 x 100 with `imshow` and, at certain points, I would like to plot hatches.

So, here is my image example:

[image]

This represents the mean of 100 samples of scalar fields. I also have the standard deviation for this samples:

[image]

So, what I would like to do is to plot the mean property combined to hatches at the positions in which I have standard deviation > 0.0.

My data are 100 x 100 and its dimension varies form -4 to 4. 
Following the idea presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045709/selective-patterns-with-matplotlib-imshow), my current approach was that:

```
plt.figure()
fig = plt.imshow(scalar_field, origin='lower', extent=(-4, 4, -4, 4))
plt.colorbar(fig)

x_indices = numpy.nonzero(standard_deviation)[0]
y_indices = numpy.nonzero(standard_deviation)[1]

ax = plt.gca()
for p in range(len(x_indices)):
    i = x_indices[p]
    j = y_indices[p]
    ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((i-.5, j-.5), 1, 1, hatch='//', fill=False, snap=False))

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

However, I don't get the patterns at the correct locations. I haven't used patches so far and I don't know if I'm using them in properly way.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert indices (0..99) to the scale of the image (-4..4) and the size of each block is not 1, 1 but 0.08,0.08. Also, you will want ec='None' in the Rectangle to remove the edges between the blocks. I believe it goes:

```
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle(((i-50.5)*0.08-.04, (j-50.5)*0.08), 0.08, 0.08, 
   hatch='//', fill=False, snap=False, linewidth=0))
```

However, I suspect that you will fill the whole area with hatching: are you certain that the stddev is in some places exactly zero (it can never be less than zero).

Comment: Yes, you're right. It can all be non zero. I will use some limit. I just use 0 here to explain.

Comment: And thank you. I was in doubt if I had to use the ndarray size or to convert them to the scale of the image (Everytime I face this problem I wasn't able to find this in some doc).

Comment: Did you find an alternative that worked (please edit my answer if yes). One alternative, by the way, would be another imshow/pcolor with alpha transparency.

Comment: I'm looking for it. If I find it, I'll show here. (: Thank you again.

Comment: Maybe the hatches are considered edges?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401348/hatched-rectangle-patches-without-edges-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding hatches in multiple rectangles, you can add them using [`contourf`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html) as explained in the [`contourf` hatching example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_hatching.html). This is a better solution as it is more general and only takes one line:

```
plt.contourf(mask, 1, hatches=['', '//'], alpha=0)
```

where `mask` is a binary image of the same size as your image. Here we set `alpha` to zero to make the mask itself transparent, and only added hatches to where the mask equals 1. Note also that the `origin` and `extent` arguments need to match, so for your code:

```
plt.contourf(standard_deviation > thresh, 1, hatches=['', '//'], alpha=0,
             origin='lower', extent=(-4, 4, -4, 4))
```

A similar solution is to use [`pcolor`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor.html) instead of `contourf`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664850/hatch-area-using-pcolormesh-in-basemap).