# Hatch area using pcolormesh in Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, significance, hatchstyle

I try to hatch only the regions where I have statistically significant results. How can I do this using Basemap and pcolormesh?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))

lons = iris_cube.coord('longitude').points
lats = iris_cube.coord('latitude').points

m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=lons[0], llcrnrlat=lats[0], urcrnrlon=lons[-1], urcrnrlat=lats[-1], resolution='l')

lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

plt.subplot(111)

cs = m.pcolormesh(lon, lat, significant_data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, hatch='/')
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems `pcolormesh` does not support hatching (see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3058). Instead, the advice is to use `pcolor`, which starting from [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html) example would look like,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dx, dy = 0.15, 0.05
y, x = np.mgrid[slice(-3, 3 + dy, dy),
                slice(-3, 3 + dx, dx)]
z = (1 - x / 2. + x ** 5 + y ** 3) * np.exp(-x ** 2 - y ** 2)
z = z[:-1, :-1]
zm = np.ma.masked_less(z, 0.3)

cm = plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z)
plt.pcolor(x, y, zm, hatch='/', alpha=0.)
plt.colorbar(cm)
plt.show()
```

where a mask array is used to get the values of z greater than 0.3 and these are hatched using `pcolor`.

[image]

To avoid plotting another colour over the top (so you get only hatching) I've set alpha to 0. in `pcolor` which feels a bit like a hack. The alternative is to use patch and assign to the areas you want. See this example [Python: Leave Numpy NaN values from matplotlib heatmap and its legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905393/python-leave-numpy-nan-values-from-matplotlib-heatmap-and-its-legend). This may be more tricky for basemaps, etc than just choosing areas with `pcolor`.

Answer (score 5):

I have a simple solution for this problem, using only `pcolormesh` and not `pcolor`: Plot the color mesh, then hatch the entire plot, and then plot the original mesh again, this time by masking statistically significant cells, so that the only hatching visible is those on significant cells. Alternatively, you can put a marker on every cell (looks good too), instead of hatching the entire figure.

(I use `cartopy` instead of `basemap`, but this shouldn't matter.)

**Step 1:** Plot your field (`z`) normally, using `pcolormesh`.

```
mesh = plt.pcolormesh(x,y,z)
```

where x/y can be lons/lats.

**Step 2:** Hatch the entire plot. For this, use `fill_between`:

```
hatch = plt.fill_between([xmin,xmax],y1,y2,hatch='///////',color="none",edgecolor='black')
```

Check details of `fill_between` to set `xmin`, `xmax`, `y1` and `y2`. You simply define two horizontal lines beyond the bounds of your plot, and hatch the area in between. Use more, or less `/`s to set hatch density.

To adjust hatch thickness, use below lines:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['hatch.linewidth'] = 0.3
```

As an alternative to hatching everything, you can plot all your x-y points (or, lon-lat couples) as markers. A simple solution is putting a dot (x also looks good).

```
hatch = plt.plot(x,y,'.',color='black',markersize=1.5)
```

One of the above will be the basis of your 'hatch'. This is how it should look after Step 2:

[image: This is how it should look after Step 2]

**Step 3:** On top of these two, plot your color mesh once again with `pcolormesh`, this time masking cells containing statistically significant values. This way, the markers on your 'insignificant' cells become invisible again, while significant markers stay visible.

Assuming you have an identically sized array containing the *t statistic* for each cell (`t_z`), you can mask significant values using `numpy`'s `ma` module.

```
z_masked = numpy.ma.masked_where(t_z >= your_threshold, z)
```

Then, plot the color mesh, using the masked array.

```
mesh_masked = plt.pcolormesh(x,y,z_masked)
```

Use `zorder` to make sure the layers are in correct order. This is how it should look after Step 3:

[image: This is how it should look after Step 3]

Comment: After Step 3 (laying the last, masked color mesh), plot border gets thinner where there is no mask. Could not figure out why. If someone can reproduce this, and does have a fix, please suggest an edit. Thanks.