# How to add black dot or circle dot as significance (p<0.05) over a spatial trend plots in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, python-xarray

I have calculated spatial **slope** and **p_value** using **scipy.stats.linregress** looping over individual pixels (lat*lon) along the time dimension. Now I can make spatial plot of slope value using **plt.pcolormesh (lat, lon, slope)**.
But over it I want to add **p_value<0.05** as dot mark wherever applicable to the same slope spatial plot. Similar to the below images.
Any help or remark regarding the same from the community............
Thanks

[example_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1gaA.jpg)

[example_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhbmn.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to ask about how to add significance (p<0.05) as dot/point over the same trend spatial map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ax.pcolor(lon, lat, hatch, hatch='..', zorder=1, alpha=0.0, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())` this worked for me!

Similar to [Hatch area using pcolormesh in Basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664850/hatch-area-using-pcolormesh-in-basemap)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, now I have added the original discussion link, from where I have followed.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.